# import a TIF image in image PIL with value of pixels of Python

Tags: python, image, import, python-imaging-library

I have a TIF image (32 bit, floating number)

[image]

and i need to import in Python

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
image = "C:\\foo.tif"
im = Image.open(image).convert('F')
im.getextrema()
(0,0)
data = np.array(im)
>>> data
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

the extrema are 0 and 0, but in the original image (32 bit, floating number) the min is 301.4110107421875 and the max is 4563.666015625

when i try to plot the image i have an empty plot

```
import pylab as pl

pl.imshow(im)
pl.show()
```

Comment: Example of the image (or link to it so we can download and check) would be useful, if possible.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for replay, I can post the pic, but i don't know how to create a link to the download

Comment: The image downloads as png, not the original tiff. But anyway, [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm) it says that for 32 float images, you need to use `F` not `L`. Maybe this will help.

Comment: also with F extrema are 0 and 0

Comment: Sorry, but dont know. Also not sure how well python's PIL supports 32 bit images. Maybe it does not. You could also have a look at [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/), or, if possible, recode images to "normal" format prior to using PIL.